# Find untranslated resources at runtime

Tags: android, android-resources

I want to find out how many string resources are not translated into the currently used app language.

I want to show my users some information like following:

> Sorry that this app is not yet translated into your language. Do you want to help translating it? Translators get this app's pro version for free.

OR

> n strings are not yet translated into your language. Do you want to help translating those strings?

**Main goal**

Encourage the users of already translated languages to help me translating new strings. Telling the user that only 10 or 20 strings need translations will encourage a lot more users to help me translating the app I think...

Additionally I can show a popup if the users wants to to inform him about new untranslated strings...

**Question**

- how can I count all strings in the default language?
- how can I count all strings in the current language (only the ones that are translated)?

At least this should be possible with a gradle script whoch generates some constants, did anybody ever do this? Any better ideas?

Comment: your title says runtime but your question says gradle script. Which is it?

Comment: Gradle script is a fallback option, I would prefer runtime but am not sure if this is even possible. The result needs to be available at runtime